# MySQL | Find all distinct strings inside a column

Tags: mysql

Beginner at MySQL. I need to extract all distinct strings that start with a dollar sign from a table.

Example:

```
id   title    text
1    hi       $yes
2    sure     $yes
3    no       $no
```

The following should return `yes` & `no`

**What I tried**

```
SELECT text FROM Messages WHERE text LIKE "%$%"
```

I can't seem to extract the word itself, I need to do that first. Then, I imagine we can do a `SELECT DISTINCT text FROM messages WHERE ______`

How do I extract that single dollar sign word?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(text,'$','') text FROM messages WHERE text IN ('$yes','$no');`

Comment: Please publish you expected result. It will be helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT replace(text, "$", "") FROM Messages WHERE text LIKE "%$%" GROUP BY text
```

Comment: what if we have: i said $yes, it would return the entire string and not just yes

Comment: You can remove the $ by the following:
SELECT replace(text, "$", "") FROM Messages WHERE text LIKE "%$%" GROUP BY text